# There is a way to upload and download file to Amazon s3 private bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have to upload and download to a private bucket in S3, but when i set the configs the bucket to private e have a denied request when im trying do upload or download as well.

How can i configure this?

Answer (score 0):

Login in the AWS console
Copy your canonical user id (see your `My security credentials`).
Go to https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3 and go to your private bucket.
You should see a page with the tabs `Overview`, `Properties`, `Permissions` and `Management`.
Ga to Permissions and look at `Access Control List`. Click on `Add account` for acces for other AWS accounts and paste your id.

Comment: Thank You. Work Perfect1